# how to get the image size in ios app coding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdate

I have retrieved an image from the imageGallery. Now I want to know about the filesize of the image, in KB. How do I do this? Please guide me. Is it possible to find it?

Comment: You can find my NSFileManager

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes you can get the size. Try the following code:

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 0.5)];
int imageSize   = imgData.length;
NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %f ", imageSize/1024.0);
```

Comment: what image type is that? is it JPEG or PNG? I am assuming jpeg here.not sure if that has an impact?

Comment: Hi, Srikar, Thanks.. [imageDate length] returns the size in KB or byte ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    BOOL isPNG = [[yourImgPath lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"];

    NSData *imageData = isPNG ?
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) :
    UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0);

    int imageSize   = imageData.length;
    NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %f ", imageSize/1024.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
NSString *imagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"jpeg"];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:imagePath error:&error];
NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
NSLog(@"size of image is : %fKB ", fileSize/1024.0);
```